# How to pass a value from PHP to Javascript without using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass the version no to javascript from php. But i dont want to use ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    init();
})

<body>
...
<input type="hidden" id="version" value="<?php echo $version; ?>
....

<script>
function init() {
   version = $('#version').val();
}
</script>
```

Can i do in this way?
Or, should i use ajax?

Comment: You can do it this way.

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="version" value=" $version;>

Comment: Your way works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do so theres no need to put it into a hidden input:

```
const version = "<?php echo $version; ?>";
```

Comment: Yea, I usually just have .php output a script block that sets the desired javascript variables.  I think that's a little clearer then passing them into a hidden element just to pass them back out to js.